# Union of array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do union of different arrays:

```
const info1 = {id: 1}
const info2 = {id: 2}
const info3 = {id: 3}

const array1 = [info1, info2]
const array2 = [info1, info3]
const array3 = [info2, info3]

const union = [...new Set([...array1, ...array2, ...array3])]

console.log(union)
```

It's possible in my code that some or all `array1`, `array2`, `array3` can be `null`, this is not shown in the code above.

However when one or more of them are `null` I get the error for example if `array1` was assigned to `null`: `array1 is not iterable`.

How can I prevent getting this error?

Comment: ...by not making them null? Or by checking if they're null before adding to the Set?

Comment: Do a `null` check before the union.

Comment: That is a bunch of `null` check that I would need to add?

Comment: Well, yeah, if you want arrays you can use arrays and have it easy, but if you also want `null` you need to deal with it somehow.

Comment: How come a null guard not a solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to fall back to an empty array if the 'array' is actually `null`.

```
const union = [
  ...new Set([...(array1 ?? []), ...(array2 ?? []), ...(array3 ?? [])]),
];
```

Comment: Please note that this operator **isn't** supported [on every browser](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_nullish_coalescing)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function that will perform the extra `null` check for you.

---

```js
const info1 = {
  id: 1
};

const info2 = {
  id: 2
};

const info3 = {
  id: 3
};

const array1 = [info1, info2];
const array2 = [info1, info3];
const array3 = [info2, info3];
const array4 = null;


// the spread operator here allow us to target every argument
// of the function
function union(...arrays) {
  // the filter removes the *nullish* values
  return Array.from(new Set(arrays.filter(x => !!x).flat()));
}

console.log(union(array1, array2, array3, array4))
```

---

**/!\ Attention**

One more thing, when you use a `Set` to remove the duplicates. It removes the duplicates because they are the same object.
If you create a new object, containing the same id, it will not be detected as the same value, because you compare *reference* and not the underlying values.

```js
const info1 = {
  id: 1
};

const info2 = {
  id: 2
};

const info3 = {
  id: 3
};

const array1 = [info1, info2];
const array2 = [info1, info3];

const array3 = [info2, {
  id: 3
}];

const array4 = null;


function union(...arrays) {
  return Array.from(new Set(arrays.filter(x => !!x).flat()));
}

console.log(union(array1, array2, array3, array4))
```

Comment: `arrays.flat().filter(x => !!x))` -> shouldn't this be `arrays.filter(x => !!x)).flat()`? Seems valid to want to know of objects that are `null` but ignore arrays that are `null`.

Comment: @VLAZ yes true!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as if an array gives you a null value then replace null with empty array to work properly as:

```js
const info1 = {id: 1}
const info2 = {id: 2}
const info3 = {id: 3}

const array1 = [info1, info2]
const array2 = [info1, info3]
const array3 = null
const isNotNull=(array)=> array ? array : []

const union = [...new Set([...isNotNull(array1), ...isNotNull(array2), ...isNotNull(array3)])]

console.log(union)
```

function isNotNull checks an array if it equals null then it return an empty array

Answer (score 1):

The most simple method is to use a [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) approach with a default array for virable with either an array or `null`.

```
unique = Array.from(new Set([array1, array2, array3].flatMap(v => v || [])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that uses the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#rest_syntax_parameters) operator to loop through each array;

Check if for null, otherwise, add to the set

```js
const info1 = {id: 1}
const info2 = {id: 2}
const info3 = {id: 3}

const array1 = [info1, info2]
const array2 = [info1, info3]
const array3 = null;

function createSet(...all) {

    // Tmp hold
    let a = [];

    // For each given array
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {

        // If it's not null, add
        if (all[i]) {
            a.push(...all[i]);
        }
    }

    // Create and return set
    return [...new Set(a)];
}


console.log(createSet(array1, array2, array3));
```